# SQL character count in table column

Tags: sql

for example i have a table called X and and column inside of it Y.

Y has 500000 values like

```
190|12131|23|123|0|0|0|0|112
220|234|23|111|0|1|0|1|769
```

in each value there are 8 `|`

but in some values there are errors and not 8 `|`

```
11|0000020|12|14 -----3 |
234|23|000|1|2 ------4 |
```

how can i list values that has less than 8 `|`

Do I need to use function? If so, how and how can I call that function. I have never used functions in SQL.

Comment: Find the length of the string then subtract from it the length minus all occurrences of | using a replace with empty set ''.  this will give you a number.  If that number is less than 8 you know it's one your interested in  .  This would also allow\ you to find ones greater than 8 since you could say where the value is <> 8. Since these functions vary from database to database, you'd need to specify the database used.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: ı use ms-sql. Thanks

Comment: can i use functions for this operation. For learning sql functions.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of counting the occurence of `|`, you could compare the length of the string with a string that has no `|`:

```
select * 
  from X
  where length(Y) <> (length(replace(Y, '|', '')) + 8)
```

Not sure if this is faster than John's answer.

Comment: Plus1 - Was my fist thought as well, and yours allows for +/- 8.  Just wasn't sure which dbms.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming max 8 |

Not elegant, nor sargible

```
Select * 
 from  X 
 Where Y not like '%|%|%|%|%|%|%|%|%'
```